# Advanced indexing/subsetting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Using NumPy, given `a` and a smaller boolean array `b`:

```
a = np.array([False, True, True, False, True])
b = np.array([False, True, False])
```

how to obtain result `c`?

```
c = np.array([False, False, True, False, False])
```

That is to do the boolean and between `b` the part of `a` which is `True` to obtain array `c` of same shape as `a` so number of elements that are `True` in `a` and length of array `b` match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
c = np.copy(a)
c[a] = b
```

First, `c` is created by copying `a`. Now, `a`, which is a boolean array, is used to select the elements of `c` where `a` is True.

Since a boolean `and` between some value and `True` is the value itself, boolean `and` between the array `b` and those elements of `a` that are `True` is simply the array `b` itself.

Finally, because the number of `True` elements of `a` is the same as the length of `b`, the assignment `c[a] = b` is possible.